# Total possible outcomes when picking up two random cards?

Tags: probability, statistics

From Thomas' Calculus (2014):

> If we select at random two cards from a 52-card deck, there are 52
> possible outcomes for the first card drawn and then 51 possibilities
> for the second card. Since the order of the cards does not matter,
> there are $ (52 * 51) / 2 = 1,326 $ possible outcomes altogether.

I understand the idea of having the probability in the first draw is 1/52 and in the second draw is 1/51. However, I had assumed then that the total possible outcomes are $ (52 * 51) = 2652 $.

Where is the division by 2 coming from?

Comment: It comes from us generally considering $A\spadesuit~10\diamondsuit$ to be the same hand as $10\diamondsuit~A\spadesuit$.  Players can rearrange their cards in whatever order they wished in many games and so it seems unnecessary to consider these to be two "different hands"

Comment: If you wish to consider these as different hands, then go ahead.  You are allowed to do that.  If you wish to consider these as the same hand, then go ahead.  You are allowed to do that.  Just make sure that if using this for probability purposes, you remain consistent with such a choice.  If your denominator has order as mattering then your numerator had better treat order as mattering as well.  The final resulting probability will of course be the same regardless of whether you treat order as relevant or not as the included divisions will cancel from top and bottom.

Comment: To emphasize... picking which sample space to use for a particular experiment *is a choice* and there can be many equally correct options to choose from.  Considerations are ease of calculation, ease of describing certain events, aesthetics, and ease of comparing to other related problems among others.  So long as calculations are performed correctly, it shouldn't matter which you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @JMoravitz, this definitely solves my question. could you please put your all comments as an answer?